# Is it possible to split 4-edge-connected graph into two non-intersecting 2-edge-connected

Tags: graph-theory

If graph can be split into two 2-edge-connected graphs that share no edge, than it is easy to show that the original graph is 4-edge-connected (Take any cut in small graphs, it has size of at least 2 in both graphs, than the size of the cut in big graph is at least 4)

Is it always possible to split 4-edge-connected graph into two 2-edge-connected? I'm struggling to prove or disprove it

Comment: Consider what this would look like for a $4$-regular, $4$-edge-connected graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This graph is the medial of the herschel graph.
[image]
It has 18 vertices and is 4 regular, so it has 36 edges. It is 4-connected. If we split it up in two graphs, we have one of the graphs with at most 18 edges. The only 2-connected graph possible on 18 vertices with that few edges is $C_{18}$. So the other graph must also be a $C_{18}$. However, it is not possible to decompose this graph in two hamiltonian cycles (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_decomposition)

Comment: Amazing! How did you come up with this?

Comment: @templatetypedef I tried with small 4 connected graphs, namely the $C_n(1,2)$ circulant graphs, but they were decomposable. However, I noticed that the smallest 4 connected graphs must be 4 regular, so the decomposition must be in two Hamiltonian cycles. Then I searched for Hamiltonian decomposition and found this graph on Wikipedia.